# cannot write an angular ui typeahed handler with typescript

Tags: typescript, angular-ui

I'm writing an angular controller using typescript, and I'm using angular ui typeahead but I receive an error during the call to the update handler.
  This is the angular directive

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.censimento.quartiere" placeholder="prima selezionare il comune"
    typeahead="address for address in vm.updateQuartieri($viewValue)"
    typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control"  />
<i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
```

this is the typescript routine

```
public updateQuartieri = (typed: string) => {
    var filtro: Factories.filtroRicercaQuartieri = new Factories.filtroRicercaQuartieri();
    filtro.testo = typed;
    filtro.idComune = this.censimento.comuneId;

    var ultimiPromise = this.censimentoFactory.quartieriComune(filtro);
    ultimiPromise.then((data: string[]) => {
            this.quartieri = data;
        },
        (reason) => {
            alert('errore in recupero lista tipi Via: ' + reason);
        }, (update) => {
            alert('Got notification: ' + update);
        });
    }
```

I suppose that the problem is that this routine never return a value, but how can I change the routine so return the result of the server call ?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution, I have to return the promise object itself changing it in

```
public updateQuartieri = (typed: string) => {
    var filtro: Factories.filtroRicercaQuartieri = new Factories.filtroRicercaQuartieri();
    filtro.testo = typed;
    filtro.idComune = this.censimento.comuneId;

    var ultimiPromise = this.censimentoFactory.quartieriComune(filtro);
    return ultimiPromise;
}
```